# How to make breadcrumb flow like text

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to cleanup a breadcrumb that flows down when longer that the width of the device while I want it to flow from the space on the line above to the next line without breaking first.

[image: How it looks on mobile]
[image: How it looks on desktop]

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="js_goback">
        <a class="__go-back" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-angle-left"></i>Back</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">
        <a href="/"><i class="fa-regular fal fa-home-alt"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">
        <a href="/">Category</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">
        <a href="/">Another category</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">
        <a href="/">Also Category</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">
        <span class="active">A very long product name that now breaks down while i do not want this to happen</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I've tried many ways like making the `li` element `display: inline;` but nothing really seems to work

Comment: Is your breadcrumb ol `display:flex`?

Comment: Yes it is, with flex wrap

Comment: That's your problem. flex items are blockified - they can't be `display:inline`.

Comment: Ahh, i see, If i make both items inline it seems to work. Thanks!